# TeamCity: Configuring Multiple Build tasks to use the Same VCS download

Tags: android, git, continuous-integration, teamcity

Our CI needs to run tests on a number of environments.

Currently we have 8 tasks, each of which does a pull from the VCS, builds the artifact, and then runs the testing.

This is for Android testing on Emulators running various version of the Android OS.

I want to change this behavior so that we have the following structure:

1)  Build Task

```
Does the VCS pull, builds the artifact for testing.
```

2)  Test Task (1...n) -

```
Snapshot Dependency on Build Task Artifact.
Starts up the emulator for its version
Runs tests
Succeeds or fails.
```

The problem I'm having is that the build task appears to blow away the repository cloned from the VCS (we're using git) after its done.  This means that the tier 2 tasks don't have access to the gradle wrapper which is in this repo.

Is there a way to stop the repo from being blown away between tasks so that I can reuse that location without doing a fresh clone for each task?

Comment: Look into the `VCS Checkout Mode` option on the Version Control Settings page of the configuration. By default it's `Automatically on server`, which means it checks out the data on the server and sends only the project data (no git data) to the agent. I'm totally guessing here, but that might have something to do with it. Try `Auto on agent` or handle it yourself with the `do not check out files` option. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Checkout+Mode

Comment: Yea I did the do not check out files option, this stops the fresh download which is great, but the issue is that in the dependent task (the Test Task) the repo is no longer on the machine anymore.  It may be that its not finding the correct directory, but I think its that the directory just doesn't exist.

Comment: @DaveZych Ahhh so you're saying on the root task, disable the auto download, include the checkout instructions there.  Run the build, then in the dependent tasks set the root to the result of the original tasks repo creation?  I just read the docs you provided and that seems like a viable possibility.

Comment: @DaveZych That looks like its going to work.  If you want to set it as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working! I added my answer. I can add to it if you think more info would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [VCS checkout mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534847/teamcity-configuring-multiple-build-tasks-to-use-the-same-vcs-download) on the configuration from `Automatically on server` to `Do not check out files automatically`. In your root task, perform the checkout into a folder accessible by the other tasks. This way Teamcity won't touch the files and remove them at any point. You can then perform a cleanup yourself if you need to.

Comment: Much appreciate the help on this one.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem using git with team city. If you need to do anything which is repository related on the agent then you have to do the checkout on the agent, which then ensures that the data is and the repo meta data is available on the agent machine.

As I recall TC will create a cache on the agents so that any future builds will only need to grab the deltas to get the updated repo so it might be slow the first time on each agent, but shouldn't need to do that same pull every time.